# How to make additional window in wxpython on a click of a button

Tags: wxpython

I need to make an additional new window in wxpython on a click of a button (which is physically seperate from primary window). I want to do this without closing the last window.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Prototype(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, title):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(1240,705))
          self.UI()
          self.Centre()
          self.Show()

     def UI(self):
          self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
          self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
          self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND) 
          b = wx.Button(self.panel1, label='second window', size=(180,100), pos=(650,25))
          b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB)        

          self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
          self.sizer.Add(self.panel2,1,flag=wx.EXPAND)
          self.panel2.Hide()
          self.panel2.SetSizer(self.vbox)
          self.SetSizer(self.sizer)  

     def OnB(self, event):
          self.panel2.Show()
          self.sizer.Layout() 

app = wx.App()
Prototype(None, title='')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
 import wx

 ########################################################################
 class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):
      """"""

      #----------------------------------------------------------------------
      def __init__(self):
           """Constructor"""
           wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Second Frame")
           panel = wx.Panel(self)
           txt = wx.StaticText(panel, label="I'm the second frame!")

 ########################################################################
 class Prototype(wx.Frame):

      #----------------------------------------------------------------------
      def __init__(self, parent, title):
           wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame", size=(1240,705))
           self.UI()
           self.Centre()
           self.Show()

      #----------------------------------------------------------------------
      def UI(self):
           self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
           self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
           self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND) 
           b = wx.Button(self.panel1, label='second window', size=(180,100), pos=(650,25))
           b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB)        

           self.SetSizer(self.sizer)  

      #----------------------------------------------------------------------
      def OnB(self, event):
           frame = SecondFrame()
           frame.Show()

 #----------------------------------------------------------------------
 app = wx.App(False)
 Prototype(None, title='')
 app.MainLoop()
```

I don't really recommend mixing sizers and absolute positioning though. You should use one or the other. I recommend using sizers unless you plan to make frames that cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new `wx.Frame` as you already did in your app. Add something along the lines to your button event handler:

```
self.second_window = wx.Frame(None)
self.second_window.Show()
```

Comment: But is it possible to keep the two windows separated?

Comment: What is your definition of "separated"? These two windows are independent on the screen. The only reason why I would add the second window to the first one as an attribute is to be able to close it again from the first window, for example using another button. That is not required.